# Setting an NTFS junction point's created/modified datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, ntfs

With normal files and directories, it's relatively easy to set their created and modified datetime in .NET.  Just create a `DirectoryInfo` for that path and set `CreationTimeUtc` and `LastWriteTimeUtc` to what you want.  However, when you create a `DirectoryInfo` for a junction point and set these properties, it resolves the junction point to its target and sets the target instead.  Oddly, when you read the properties, they in fact show the created/modified datetime of the junction point itself.

How can I set the junction point's datetimes?

Comment: Another name for a Junction in NTFS is [a Reparse Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point). I found here that [".NET Framework's FileAttributes enumeration includes the value FileAttributes.ReparsePoint but there is no other built-in support for Reparse Points."](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15633/Manipulating-NTFS-Junction-Points-in-NET) as of 2006.

Comment: The BCL has no support for manipulating junctions that way. You'll have to P/Invoke down to `CreateFile` to pass `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`, then use `SetFileTime` on the resulting handle. None of the managed classes help you with this as there is no public API for setting file times on a handle you obtained, but you can look at the source of `Directory.SetLastAccessTime` for inspiration.